# Tfs build two projects with different changeset

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild

In visual studio,  We have a solution that contains two projects. We need to build project A from a specific changeset, but project B with the latest sources.  In TFS is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Does the project rely on another one? For example, project B has some dependencies on project A.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to build yes , this can be achieved from what i know.You would have to get the project with the Specific build which you want and keep the other with latest build on your visual studio and build it... If you have all the references pointed out correctly then you can build. If you want to save this build in TFS then you can create a new branch on your project and save this there.